# Interacting main regressor of interest with a region indicator variable, do I interact all controls with the indicator as well?

Tags: regression, econometrics, interpretation, categorical-encoding

Lets say I am running a regression at the state year level as the following:

$y_{s,t} = \beta_o + \beta_1 x_{s,t} + controls_{s,t} + \mu_s + \tau_t + \eta_{s,t}$

Where x is the regressor of interest, controls are a vector of control variables, and $\eta$ is the error term, $mu_s$ and $\tau_t$ are state and year fixed effects. After running this analysis, I wish to look at hetereogeneity by region, and thus I decided to interact x with an indicator for 5 defined regions of the US (and the region dummies by themselves are absorbed by the state fixed effects).

Should I also interact all the control variables with the region dummy as well? or does it suffice to focus on the variable of interest? What am I implicitly assuming by doing either?

Comment: As to what you are implicitly assuming by doing either; If you are not interacting your control variables by region, you are assuming that your controls have a homogeneous effect across regions. If you do interact your controls, you are accounting for the possibility that controls affect regions differently. Considering those assumptions, it would appear that including all interactions would always be preferable. Because why would you assume, if you don't have to. I think you have to check however, if by doing so you might not unintentionally remove any variation in your variable of interest.

Comment: If I may go out on a limb: Because evaluating the last sentence of my previous comment is a very tough one (which I for example hardly ever feel able to properly make), I would argue that you only interact your control variables if you have a reason to suspect the effecs of these controls would vary substantially by region. This might be a nice point for discussion however. I think interacting your controls would also touch on the subject of over controlling, but I leave it for someone else to comment on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

This [blog post](http://datacolada.org/80), gives an example where the confounding effect of the control variables is different than the confounding effect of the control variables with an interaction. So, the author advocates interacted controls when the regressor of interest is an interaction. However, he notes that this doesn't seem to be common practice (as of 2019) in applied econometrics papers.

From a model-stability perspective, you may need to evaluate whether your sample size can even support interactions between region and the controls. This is often the limiting factor in my work.

Comment: I follow his reasoning, but I am wondering if it is just a coincidence that adding the interaction did not lead to a different outcome (and that the coefficients on the interactions were nearly identical). Is there really a difference between accounting for viewership and accounting for loss and win viewership (are you not already doing that) ? Also, sticking to his reasoning, shouldn't the interaction have been with upset loss?

Comment: Good question. I suppose the argument is that the confounding effect of viewership during a loss is different than the confounding effect of viewership in general. In this case, there wasn't much difference though.